# Meteor: How to Perform Calculations Client-Side on Mongo Data

Tags: javascript, html, mongodb, canvas, meteor

In my Meteor app, I've successfully published data server-side and subscribed to that data client-side. Now, rather than pushing raw data straight to the client's screen, I want to store it as a javascript object, perform some calculations on it (number crunching), and render the result on the client's screen (within an HTML5 canvas element). Every time Mongo is updated, the javascript code should re-run (i.e. the js object is re-set, calculations are performed again from that object, and the new results are rendered on the canvas).

I can grab hold of Mongo data using the `Template.example.helpers` block and show that *directly* in the client as follows:

---

```
Meteor.subscribe('collection','query');

Template.example.helpers({
  sampleData: function(){
    return Collection.findOne({query:`query`});
  }
});
```

---

```
<template name="example">
  <div>
    {{sampleData.last}}
  </div>
  <canvas id="test-canvas"></canvas>
</template>
```

---

But what I'm trying to do is grab hold of this data before pushing to the client's screen, within the `Template.example.rendered` block:

```
Meteor.subscribe('collection','query');

Template.example.rendered = function(){
  // define HTML5 canvas and context variables
  var canvas = $("#test-canvas")[0];
  var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
  // store Mongo data as Javascript variable
  // loop over this variable and perform calculations
    // draw results to the canvas
}
```

Am I approaching this the right way? If so, how can I achieve it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out my own answer to the question posed above. My template was loading *before* the data was retrieved by the client, therefore I kept getting `cannot read property <blank> of undefined` in the browser's javascript console and code would interrupt. You need to use the `iron-router` package in order to

1) set the "data context" of the template you are working on (package up an object containing data sources you need for that specific template), and

2) force the template not to render until the data has been retrieved. Once the data is retrieved, iron-router loads the template and you now have full javascript control of the data object you created above.

**Steps at a high-level:**

1) Install iron-router

2) Define a route for the template

3) Use the `waitOn` method to tell iron-router which data source you are subscribing to (which data it is waiting on)

4) Define a "loading" template (aka splash screen) to show while data is being retrieved before template load. As per https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/issues/554, you can achieve this by inserting this block of code in your iron-router `router.js` file:

```
Router.onBeforeAction(function(pause) {
  if (!this.ready()) {
    this.render('loading'); // wait
    pause();                // ready
  }
});
```

Just make sure you create a `loading` template to go along with this.

5) Use the `data` method to set the data context for your template (create the data object to be used in the template)

**Steps at a detailed-level:**

http://www.manuel-schoebel.com/blog/iron-router-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

It would be probably easier to store the data and perform the calculations in a seperate object and render the template from the object and not straight from the mongo, you can easily keep your templates reactive using "Deps" and it will make you code much more maintainable.

Comment: Can you please provide some code examples to go along with your explanation? I'm still learning Meteor, so I'm having some trouble wrapping my head around your reply. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is good.
The key here is to `observe` collection and update canvas when items in collections are:

- `added(document)` or `addedAt(document, atIndex, before)`
- `removed(oldDocument)` or `removedAt(oldDocument, atIndex)`
- `changed(newDocument, oldDocument)` or `changedAt(newDocument, oldDocument, atIndex)`
- `movedTo(document, fromIndex, toIndex, before)`

There is also more performant way to [observe changes in collection](http://docs.meteor.com/#observe_changes).
Code similar to below should help you:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Template.example.rendered = function () {
   var canvas = $("#test-canvas")[0];
   var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
   Collection.find().observe({
      added: function (doc) {              // draw sth on canvas          },
      changed: function (doc) {            // draw sth on canvas          },
      movedTo: function (doc) {            // draw sth on canvas          },
      removed: function (doc) {            // remove sth from canvas      }
    });
  };
}
```

Example: https://github.com/Slava/d3-meteor-basic

Comment: Hey Kuba - this seems to work well for monitoring documents as wholes. But how do you handle changes WITHIN documents? I'm trying to monitor changes to existing documents (document count is fixed) - any advice there? I want to store added/removed values client side so I can perform calculations on them.

Comment: See [documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/#observe). There are also handlers like : `changed`, `movedTo`. Also take a look at [observeChanges](http://docs.meteor.com/#observe_changes)